# Drag&Drop Primefaces Dashboard "OnDrop" - Event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I´m currently working on a drag&drop  project with PrimeFaces.
I have a `p:dataGrid` with multiple panels:

```
 <p:fieldset id="availableBlocksField">
    <p:dataGrid id="availableBlocks" columns="1" var="block" value="#{blockmenu.blockMenuItems}">
        <p:panel id="drag" header="#{block.header}">
           #{block.thumbnail}
        </p:panel>
        <p:draggable opacity="0.6" for="drag" helper="clone" dashboard="mainForm:dropArea">
         </p:draggable>
    </p:dataGrid>
 </p:fieldset>
```

and a dashboard with `binding`:

```
    <p:dashboard id="dropArea" binding="#{blockdashboard.dashboard}" styleClass="blockDashboardView" >

        <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{blockdashboard.onReorder}"/>
    </p:dashboard>
```

With the "MenuItems" I have my available items that I can add to the dashboard but if I add them to my dashboard they are only ClientSide. My `Bean` never get known to these Items.

How can i fix this?